# Elasticsearch: upserts no longer support versions problem during migration ES from 5.6.16 to 6.8

Tags: elasticsearch

My use case is: I get a document from ES, process a time consuming operation, merge its results with the document and update document with the same version.
I want to be sure that when I process the time consuming operation no other update will affect my document.

I upgrade Elasticsearch from 5.6.16 to 6.8 and I have client 5.6.16.

My code:

```
client.prepareUpdate(indexName, documentType, documentId)
                .setRouting(sellerId)
                .setDoc(jsonEntity, XContentType.JSON)
                .setUpsert(jsonEntity, XContentType.JSON)
                .setVersion(version)
                .setVersionType(VersionType.INTERNAL)
                .get();
```

During update ES throws an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation Failed: 1: can't provide both upsert request and a version;
```

In ES [Breaking changes in 6.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/breaking-changes-6.0.html#_link_linkend_upserts_upserts_link_no_longer_support_versions) I found:

"Upserts no longer support versions. Adding a version to an upsert request is no longer supported."

What should I use instead setting a version when I want to migrate to Elasticsearch 6.8?

Comment: You can read more about that change here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16438

Answer (score -1):

_version can not used to version contorl , you can find more detail at
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/optimistic-concurrency-control.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).